# Does not update while pressing update on my articles while editing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cloud9-ide

My problem is that after I edit the article it reverts back to its old self

These are my pictures representing the steps I took while trying to edit:

Before editing:

[image]

After editing:

[image]

after pressing the update button:
[image]

my code:

articles_controller:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end 

  def new
    @article = Article.new 
  end

  def edit 
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end 

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    if @article.save 
      flash[:notice] = "article was updated"
      redirect_to(@article)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end 
  end 

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    if @article.update(article_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Article was submitted succsefully"
      redirect_to (@article)
    else
      render 'new'
    end 
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end 

  private 

  def article_params 
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :description)
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you add the form you're using? And also, to format your code, is difficult to read.

Comment: I try my best I really don't know how to format... anyway I don't think I use any form... by any chance can you explain to me what you are talking about then perhaps I will put it in the question If I understand what you are saying or if I have it, Thanks for trying to help

Comment: The form to send the data, it looks like an scaffold, you should have a `_form.html.erb` file under the `views/articles`.

Comment: nope I do not have it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `update` action:

```
  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    if @article.save 
      flash[:notice] = "article was updated"
      redirect_to(@article)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end 
  end
```

you never assign `article_params` to `@article`. You want to do something like:

```
  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.update_attributes article_params
    if @article.save 
      flash[:notice] = "article was updated"
      redirect_to(@article)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end 
  end
```

Using `assign_attributes` sets the attributes without doing a save so that you can do your `if @article.save` test.